# Shrinking text to fit one line label when using setAttributedTitle

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I need to use subscript and superscript so I have used NSMutableAttributedString to offset specific characters.

I need an equivalent of:

```
mybutton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
mybutton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
mybutton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

but for attributed strings?

Any starters much appreciated. Best wishes.

Comment: How do you want the label to understand fitting if you set numberOfLines to 0? You either fit it to the width in a single line by setting numberOfLines = 1, or allow it to write text in any number of lines by setting numberOfLines = 0, then text won't be fit.

Comment: Sorry, code above was from another app and works fine. I believe the issue is where i have used myButton.setAttributedTitle.... rather than myButton.setTitle... The above code, with or without the 0/1 doesn't seem to work with setAttributedTitle